# I want to display UTF - 8 encoded string in my mobile app

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, html-entities

I want to UTF-8 encode a string "$username" in order to display the same in Arabic in my mobile app (Android/iOS). My server side language is php. I have tried the following code:

```
$username = "&#1571;&#1581;&#1605;&#1583; &#1575;&#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1607;&#1610;&#1605;&#1575;&#1576;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;";

$tmp1 = htmlentities($username, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$name = utf8_encode($tmp1); 

return $name;
```

Please suggest me an alternative solution if any.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `default_charset` in your php.ini `utf-8`?

Comment: yes default_charset in my php.ini is utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
$username = "&#1571;&#1581;&#1605;&#1583; &#1575;&#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1607;&#1610;&#1605;&#1575;&#1576;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;&#1600;";

$name = utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($username));

return $name;
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Faisal. But that didn't work for me.